# displaying a row of data based on a set condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following data below:

```
Account number ------   updated date -----   changed date  ----  Item code  

00991    -------------------22/07/2016----------12/07/2016--------S2

00991-------------------19/07/2016-----------12/07/2016--------S2

00991-------------------12/07/2016-----------12/07/2016--------S2

00991------------------10/07/2016------------05/07/2016--------ZR

00991------------------06/07/2016-----------05/07/2016---------ZR

00991------------------05/07/2016------------05/07/2016--------ZR

00991------------------02/07/2016------------01/07/2016 -------TV
```

I've been trying to use a case when statement to obtain the row i want

```
'00991------------------10/07/2016------------05/07/2016--------ZR'
```

as seen here 'Case when updated_date <= changed_date then display said row as shown above else don't display anything at all end' I believe this is the best method to select the row of information i want from the table above when trying to select the previous item code of ZR. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not completely understanding your question, could you elaborate further?

Comment: The row you show as the one you want does not meet the criterion you provided (`updated_date <= changed_date`). Did you either mean to use `>=` or provide the wrong record in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this ?

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE 
updated_date <= changed_date
```

Comment: Thanks, kicking myself now